# How to hide footer in subreport in jasper

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a subreport and page footer in main report, and i need to hide page footer for the subreport part. Is there any way to achieve this?

Details:
I have main report. It has several detail bands and a page footer. One of detail bands (Detail 4) is filled with data returned from query. After this band goes "Detail 5" band that has only subreport in it, which is the last detail band. My subreport contains several pages of text. I need page footer from my main report not to be shown in this pages. So what I need is: page footer should be applied to pages, that are generated in detail bands 1-4, but not "Detail 5" .

Comment: Have you tried to delete it from supreports jrxml?

Comment: Sure, there is no footer band in subreport

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. Can you provide a screenshot or something to illustrate what you want vs. what you have?

Comment: it would be easy to not have a page # on the last page of a report by adding **Last page footer** band of the report But i am not sure this is what you want

Comment: Nope. I need to hide page footer on several pages, starting from detail 5 band, which contains subreport

Comment: Do You solved this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the size of your details bands vary (and quite possibly the size of your subreport as well) you cannot be certain about the page numbers that the pages of your sub report will appear on. But that would be necessary knowledge to create a proper `print when` expression for the footer band to achieve the behavior you want.

In other words: it's most likely not possible to do that.